# How to use a class defined in another .uml file using Papyrus UML?

Tags: uml, tool-uml

I'm Using Papyrus UML and I have to use in my diagram, a class which is defined in another .uml file. HowI can do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a shortcut but for me this is not usable because I prefer to mix usecase and class diagram elements inside the same model and sometimes even the same diagram.

You can do it with RSA IBM or Omondo EclipseUML.

Comment: But I have a set of classes that i need to use in more than one diagram.

Comment: Change tool and you will be able to do it !!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know particularly about Papyrus, but in UML in general, you should have a `Model`-element at the top-level, and in there, you create a `PackageImport`. Now you should be able to set the ``Imported Package'' reference---but the other UML must be loaded from the workspace first:

This is where things become interesting! in the plain Eclipse UML editor, you have to load the resource first using the 'UML Editor' menu or the ``Additional Resources'' sub-tree in the model-outline. I guess Papyrus offers at least the same way through the outline.